# Why my function is not present in bundle.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a simple JS web app where I have a function in my main.js which handle my button onclick event.

index.html:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-dark" value="Submit" onclick="onSubmitButtonPressed()">

...

<script src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

main.js:

```
function onSubmitButtonPressed() {
    // some DOM manipulating stuff 
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './main.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/dist'
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 8000,
    }
}
```

I am using webpack and seems like my `onSubmitButtonPressed()` function is not generated into bundle.js

---

Additional info:

I tried to export my function like this:

```
module.exports = {
    onSubmitButtonPressed: onSubmitButtonPressed(),
}
```

After this my function is generated into bundle.js like this, but not working:

```
e.exports = {
        onSubmitButtonPressed: function () {
            const e = document.getElementById("input-text").value;
            r.push(e);
            let t = document.createElement("LI");
            t.innerHTML = e, t.className = "list-group-item", n.appendChild(t)
        }()
    }
```

When I don't use my bundle.js only the main.js then everything is working fine.

---

Based on the below suggestion (original issue solved), I updated my

webpack.config.js with:

```
optimization: {
    minimize: false 
}
```

I have my onSubmitButtonPressed() function in my bundle.js:

```
...

function onSubmitButtonPressed() {
    const inputText = document.getElementById('input-text').value;
    items.push(inputText)
    let child = document.createElement("LI");
    child.innerHTML = inputText;
    child.className = 'list-group-item';
    itemsUl.appendChild(child);
    console.log('Called');
}

window.onSubmitButtonPressed = onSubmitButtonPressed

...
```

And I also add this line in order to make my function  to make it globally available:

```
window.onSubmitButtonPressed = onSubmitButtonPressed
```

Comment: likely webpack didn't see it in use, so it was optimized out. i'd consider a modern mv* framework.

Comment: Could you add your webpack config?

Comment: Why are you calling the function in the export?

Comment: I updated my question with webpack.config.js.

So the problem maybe that webpack didn't see it in use as @DanielA.White mentioned.

To export this function was just a try, but it's not working (understandable why).

Comment: @BalázsFodor-Pap I think the fact the function is being called on export might also hinder it working correctly

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes, but it was just for test purposes. After I removed the export call, the issue is still present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webpack is [tree shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) your function as it's not called or referenced throughout your entrypoint. Also, even if it wasn't tree shaken, webpack is a module bundler, so it would scope your function if it weren't declared on the global scope (i.e. `window.myFunction = function(arg) { return arg }`).

> Tree shaking is a term commonly used in the JavaScript context for dead-code elimination. It relies on the static structure of ES2015 module syntax, i.e. import and export. The name and concept have been popularized by the ES2015 module bundler rollup.

[Here's a solution](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7978#issuecomment-550455244) that seems to correspond with your use-case.

Comment: Okay, it's new for me and I understand this. I disable minimalization with:

    optimization: {
        minimize: false
    }

And my function is now correctly present in bundle.js but I got the following error: 

(index):18 Uncaught ReferenceError: onSubmitButtonPressed is not defined.

Comment: Sure, I updated it. Thanks for this Answer btw, it answered my original question.

Comment: As Jay mentioned in his answer, even without tree shaking the function that are declared in modules are not global. You'd not be able to access module's function from DOM onclick attribute directly. Either assign your function to `window.onSubmitButtonPressed` in main.js, or (better approach) add event listener using addEventLiistener https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: Excellent answer, I didn't know how to phrase it. Great job

Comment: You'll need to attach onSubmitButtonPressed to the window: window.onSubmitButtonPressed = function(args) { ... }

Answer (score 0):

This is because webpack treats `function onSubmitButtonPressed` as a local (not global) function.

Use `window.onSubmitButtonPressed = onSubmitButtonPressed` at the end of the file to make it globally available.